# Is it possible to create a Blazor component on button's onclick event

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazorise

I am very new with Blazor. Hence all guidance and direction regarding my question is highly appreciated.

I am working on a Blazor page where I have implemented Blazorise open source library to implement `<CardDeck>...</CardDeck>` in a Page(eg. Parent.razor). Underneath that `CardDeck` I have implemented a `Card` inside razor component. And I am binding data objects retrieved from database.

**Code for Parent.razor is like below.**

```
    <CardDeck>
          <Button @onclick="SomeMethodToCreateComponent"
          @foreach(var item in List)
          {
             //implementing component page (eg. CardComponent.razor)
             <CardComponent>...</CardComponent>
          }
    </CardDeck>

    @Code{
        public void SomeMethodToCreateComponent()
        {
             //Code to create a component on button onclick
        }
    }
```

**Code for component page (eg. Card.razor)**

```
    <Card>
     <CardBody>
        <CardTitle Size="5">Card title 1</CardTitle>
        <CardText>
            Lorem ipsum
        </CardText>
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
```

Now there is an enhancement to this functionality. On parent razor page, I have a placed a button. On that button's `@onclick` event I need to generate a component with `<Card>...</Card>` hierarchy. Whenever the button in parent page is clicked, a card should be generated. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler than you think.

```
public void SomeMethodToCreateComponent()
{
     //Code to create a component on button onclick
     var newItem = ...
     List.Add(newItem);
} // auto re-render here and the @foreach will render the new item
```